# Concatenate columns and adds digits awk

Tags: awk, addition, concatenation, cut

I have a csv file:

```
number1;number2;min_length;max_length
"40";"1801";8;8  
"40";"182";8;8  
"42";"32";6;8  
"42";"4";6;6  
"43";"691";9;9
```

I want the output be:

```
4018010000;4018019999  
4018200000;4018299999  
42320000;42329999
423200000;423299999
4232000000;4232999999
42400000;42499999  
43691000000;43691999999
```

So the new file will be consisting of:

> column_1 = a concatenation of old_column_1 + old_column_2 + a number
>   of "0" equal to (old_column_3 - length of the old_column_2)
>
> column_2 = a concatenation of old_column_1 + old_column_2 + a number of "9" equal
>   to (old_column_3 - length of the old_column_2) , when min_length = max_length. And when min_length is not equal with max_length , I need to take into account all the possible lengths. So for the line "42";"32";6;8 , all the lengths are: 6,7 and 8.

Also, i need to delete the quotation mark everywhere.

I tried with paste and cut like that:

```
paste -d ";" <(cut -f1,2 -d ";" < file1) > file2
```

for the concatenation of the first 2 columns, but i think with awk its easier. However, i can't figure out how to do it. Any help it's apreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Actually, added column 4 in input.

Comment: Welcome to SO, special thanks for showing all your efforts in your post. But your logic of getting expected output is not clear, could you please do add more details on same and let us know then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk 'function padstr(ch, len, s) {
   s = sprintf("%*s", len, "")
   gsub(/ /, ch, s)
   return s
}
BEGIN {
   FS=OFS=";"
}
{
   gsub(/"/, "");
   for (i=0; i<=($4-$3); i++) {
      d = $3 - length($2) + i
      print $1 $2 padstr("0", d), $1 $2 padstr("9", d)
   }
}' file
```

```
4018010000;4018019999
4018200000;4018299999
42320000;42329999
423200000;423299999
4232000000;4232999999
42400000;42499999
43691000000;43691999999
```

Comment: I think you meant `awk 'function padstr(ch, len) {` instead of `awk 'function padstr(ch, len, s) {`

Comment: @anishsane: This is actually a work-around in `awk` to make sure variable `s` used inside function remains local to function.

Comment: @anubhava , thanks a lot! This works! I figure out that i should take into account another column. I edited my input file. I thought that all the time min_len = max_len, but it seems i was wrong. So i need to take into account all the possible length from min_length to max_length.

Comment: Hmm. I guessed so. But I did not know if not passing the third parameter during calling it is accepted.

Comment: I tested and this works as expected. Thanks a lot! I really apreciate!

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
awk '
    BEGIN{FS = OFS = ";"}  # set field separator and output field separator to be ";"
    {
        $0 = gensub("\"", "", "g"); # Drop double quotes
        s = $1$2; # The range header number
        l = $3-length($2); # Number of zeros or 9s to be appended
        l = 10^l; # Get 10 raised to that number
        print s*l, (s+1)*l-1; # Adding n zeros is multiplication by 10^n
                              # Adding n nines is multipliaction by 10^n + (10^n - 1)
    }' input.txt
```

Explanation inline as comments.

Comment: thank, this works, but i found out thai i need to take into account a column number 4.